# desktop built-in VGA port and Nvidia geforce210 for dual monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a problem on my monitor, one monitor is connected to the built-in VGA port and the other one is connected on my video card which is a NVIDIA GeForce210. At first the two monitor work but when I installed the driver for the NVIDIA GeForce210 the monitor connected to the built-in VGA port stopped working (it's not being detected anymore).

When I run `xrandr`, this is the result:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 413mm x 234mm
   1366x768       59.8*+
   1360x768       60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     72.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
   640x400        70.1  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And `sudo lshw -c video`:

```
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
    DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    VGA-0 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 413mm x 234mm
       1366x768       59.8*+
       1360x768       60.0  
       1024x768       75.0     72.0     70.1     60.0  
       800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
       640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9  
       640x400        70.1  
    DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

And `sudo lshw -c video`: 

*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GT218 [GeForce 210]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:45 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:43 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```